# Attachments not working with logstash output slack plugin

Tags: logstash, slack, slack-api, logstash-configuration

My Grok filter is this:

```
 grok {
        match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} Thread:'(?<thread>[^']+)' Level:'%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}' Message:%{GREEDYDATA:information}"]
```

And this works fine in output:

```
slack
        {
           url => "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
           format => "%{log-level} at %{@timestamp} on %{type} \n\n Message: %{information}"
        }
```

Attachments don't work, also `\n` too doesn't break the lines and its just displayed in Slack as \n

My Error message logs are multi line large chunks of text, so i really wanted to do something like this, which isn't working:

```
slack
        {
           url => "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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"
           format => "%{log-level} at %{@timestamp} on %{type} with IP:%{host}"
           attachments => "Message: %{information}"
        }
```